# Alternative to NSDictionary with single object/key

Tags: objective-c, c, syntax, struct, nsdictionary

Say I want to have an item that holds a string as a value to a key, using a dictionary I would write:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someString" forKey:@"stringKey"];
```

I'm asking how to do this without a dictionary (ambiguous, the programmer needs to know the key) or an object (overkill for this thin object, no need for methods), something more in the lines of structs, I tried structs before, but I haven't seen any struct in iOS that uses `chars` as struct items, so I'm not sure that this is the way to go. The result should be similar to this:

```
replacement.key = value;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why can't you use `NSDictionary`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Can you give an example or some background?

Answer (score 2):

A small data object is seldom overkill unless you have a very specialized problem. For example, if you had many thousands of these objects, and particularly if you needed to create and destroy them quickly, and you had profiled your app and discovered that the objects themselves were a real problem, then you should consider not using simple data objects. But in the general case, you should use simple data objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if it what you want, but you **can** use a `struct`:

```
 typedef struct {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* key;
   ...
 } foo;

 foo bar;
 NSString* foobar = @"Hello";
 bar.key = foobar;
```

Attention, there is no reason for ARC not to dispose this value. But if you have a strong reference to the value, you can use it.

Comment: How would one use this to get a value from that key?

Comment: My understanding was, that the OP want to access a component by name, i.e., like in a "normal" C `struct`. `key` is here simply the **symbol** to address the component of the struct, not a key as in KVC.

Comment: The above is extremely dangerous. The string can be discarded at any time and your `key` would become a dangling pointer. While possible, it should be strongly avoided unless there is no other solution. There's a reason that the word "unsafe" is right there in the text.

Comment: will using chars instead of NSString will make a difference?

Comment: Well, thanks everyone, this is what i was looking for, just that you can't use it to store the struct for future reference, just for passing data around. correct me if you know otherwise

Comment: @RobNapier you are right, that is why I said "attention" :-)  Yogev Shelly: you can always use 'pure' C constructs, since ObjC is an extension of C.

Comment: If you use char* rather than NSString, then yes, that's just C, so it will work. But you must memory manage the char* (or use a fixed-length string). This is a lot of overhead to avoid a little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

A thin object with `@property` and `@synthesize` will save you any pain of creating methods. All instance variable will be created and modified without any code of yours.

Such an object definition would hardly be larger than a struct, and, being a subclass of `NSObject`, it can be put in any array or other framework containers which only accept `NSObject` subclasses. You won't be able to do that with structs.

If you use XCode 4.4 (for Mac development) or 4.5 (for iOS), you'll even be able to drop `@synthesize` and only have `@property`.

Only if you're really tight on performance and need to get away from `NSObject` hierarchy you should be considering dropping it and using C structs.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the dictionary but create a set of NSString constants that will work as the key? Then there will be less ambiguity.

For example consider Apple's key constant used for retrieving a localized string from a NSError's userInfo dictionary `NSLocalizedDescriptionKey`. [Many other keys are used as well to retrieve specific parts of information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-CJBIAHGF) and because these keys are constants, they're easy to use in Xcode (autocompletion). Another example of using string constants to retrieve values out of an NSDictionary could be [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW2).

Additionally, just using an object should be fine as well, in most cases the 'overhead' should be negligible - certainly not anything a user would notice. At the very least, [please don't try to prematurely optimize your code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) for situations that *might* ever happen in the very far future ...

Comment: i usually go with #define for key but that would work as well, you still need to let the programer know that these are the right key. so many Stack Overlfow questions can be averted